# Re-read/Reload Grails configuration files without restarting container

Tags: grails

Is it possible to have grails re-read its configuration files based on a trigger without having to restart/reload web app or container?

The trigger could be anything from a kill signal to a file change or maybe a JMX operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this plugin:

[External Configuration Reload](http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload)